# What is the state of the art method for doing face recognition?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, face-recognition

In school we learned about a method called 'eigenfaces' of applying PCA to many images to do face recognition.  I was wondering, what is the approach most commonly used today to do face recognition?

I am hoping to do face recognition based on many images of different sizes and different views.  Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Eigenface is one of most famous classic method for face recognition. If you talk about recent popular method, you can check 
Robust Face Recognition via Sparse Representation, John Wright, Allen Yang, Arvind Ganesh, Shankar Sastry, and Yi Ma, IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence (PAMI), 2009.

According to your description of your target, you may take a look at recognition multiple images (image set). I personally maintain a [literature](https://sites.google.com/site/yiqunhu/Home/set-based-recognition) of classification based on image set. You can also check out my latest paper
[Face Recognition using Sparse Approximated Nearest Points between Image Sets](https://sites.google.com/site/yiqunhu/cresearch/sanp), Yiqun Hu, Ajmal S. Mian and Robyn Owens, IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence (PAMI).

However, I have to say that face recognition techniques for an controlled environment is quite mature, the challenges still remain for the uncontrolled environment, where face images are not aligned, the view angles are different and the lighting conditions are dramatically different.